# Why jQuery.css does not apply a property if it is not supported and how is this being checked?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm a bit confused. I expected from $.css() method to dumbly add a css property to an element no matter what. You know, just like in Chrome Dev tools, when you apply any css property to an element and it simply appears in HTML. But apparently it somehow checks if it supported. For example, if you run this command:

```
$('#element').css('display','block'); /* returns jQuery object) */
$('#element').css('display') /* returns "block" */
```

But if you put something like

```
$('#element').css('hurr','durr');
$('#element').css('hurr') /* returns undefined */
```

So, jQuery checks if property is appliable?

Another example. Opera currently does not support CSS filters. Or does it? Well, I used a [method described here](http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/check-if-a-css-property-is-supported/) and surprisingly it returned `true` for 'filter'. Then I tried to apply it with $.css:

```
$('#element').css('filter','blur(5px)');
$('#element').css('filter') /*returns "" (an empty string) *
```

So, not only does jQuery check if an element is supported but even checks if value is legit. How exactly does it do that? What is the right way to check if a property is supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is indeed filtering out some values, but it isn't doing it intentionally in this case.  It has to do with how it retrieves the styles using `getComputedStyle()` which apparently knows that `"hurr"` isn't a valid style so it isn't returned as part of that and then when jQuery looks for `"hurr`" in the computed style, it isn't there so it returns `undefined`.

In Chrome, the style value does appear to actually be there on the style object, even when set via jQuery, but it isn't retrieved properly by `.css()` because it's not a real style.

If you want to set an unsupported style value, you can just use the style object directly but according to some comments in the jQuery code, some versions of IE might throw an exception if you try to set something it doesn't know about:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("element");
elem.style.hurr = "durr";
console.log(elem.style.hurr);   // in Chrome, gives you "durr"
```

Comment: @Juribiyan - After tracing through jQuery `.css("hurr")`, I found that the style is actually being set on the object via jQuery, but not read back and I've added some info on that to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The css function does a lot of work to standardise the different ways each browser accesses the various css properties - for example, the W3C standard property for float is `cssFloat`, but Internet Explorer calls it `styleFloat`.

Because of this, jQuery only works with accepted css properties. `filter` is a proprietary (browser-specific) property.

Comment: Actually, the standardization of properties by jQuery doesn't have anything to do with why `.css()` doesn't retrieve the `"hurr"` style value.  If you step through `.css("hurr")`, you can see that it has to do with how jQuery retrieves the style value via `window.getComputedStyle()` which only returns actual style properties.  See more info in my answer.